# Find a norm for $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $B : \mathbb{R}^{d} \to \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be a linear isomorphism such that all eigenvalues ​​have absolute value less than $1$. Show that there is some norm in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ for which the operator norm of $B$ is less than $1$.

---

The operator norm is

$$\| B \| := \sup \, \left\{ \| B(x)\| : \| x \|_2 \leq 1 \right\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3760678/144766), let $J = P^{-1}BP$ be the Jordan form of $B$ and define $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,\varepsilon, \varepsilon^2, \ldots, \varepsilon^{n-1})$. Notice that $$(D^{-1}JD)_{ij} = \varepsilon^{j-i}J_{ij}$$
and hence $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} D^{-1}JD$ is precisely the diagonal of $J$, which contains numbers of absolute value $<1$. Hence we can pick $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough so that $\|D^{-1}JD\|_\infty < 1$, where the infinity norm is induced by sup-norm on vectors:$$\|A\|_\infty = \sup_{v \ne 0} \frac{\|Av\|_\infty}{\|v\|_\infty}.$$ Define a vector norm $$\|v\| := \|(PD)^{-1}v\|_\infty.$$
In the corresponding matrix norm we have
$$\|B\| = \sup_{v \ne 0} \frac{\|(PD)^{-1}Bv\|_\infty}{\|(PD)^{-1}v\|_\infty} = \sup_{w\ne 0} \frac{\|D^{-1}P^{-1}BPDw\|_\infty}{\|(PD)^{-1}PDw\|_\infty} = \sup_{w\ne 0}\frac{\|D^{-1}JDw\|_\infty}{\|w\|_\infty} = \|D^{-1}JD\|_\infty < 1$$
where we used the substitution $v = PDw$ which is valid since $PD$ is invertible.